# Is there a SAML library for The Go Language?

Tags: go, saml-2.0

I see that the [goauth](https://github.com/alloy-d/goauth) and [go-oauth](https://github.com/garyburd/go-oauth) OAuth libraries have been written for the [Go Programming Language](http://golang.org/), but a couple of hours of searching online turns up nothing for [SAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0).

I would like to use Go to implement SSO support using SAML for a web service, but without a SAML library for Go it looks like I will have to "wrap" the SAML logic in a separate service, implemented in another language.

Does anyone know of a Go-friendly SAML library, or maybe some some trick for using a Java, C, or PHP library from a Go program?

Comment: You can wrap a C library really easily in Go using CGO. Details here: http://golang.org/doc/articles/c_go_cgo.html

Comment: Thanks for the link! It's nice to know that I at least have the option of writing a Go wrapper for [Lasso](http://lasso.entrouvert.org/), for example. It would of course be nice if Google were to provide a SAML library for their language and save me the trouble.

Comment: If your SAML use case is simple enough you can implement it yourself with no library support pretty easily. Here is an example: http://sanatgersappa.blogspot.com/2012/11/querying-sharepoint-on-office365-with-go.html

Comment: @voidlogic - that's hardly a usable saml implementation. It's roughly the equivalent of basic password auth, and most systems wouldn't allow that assertion.

Answer (score 12):

I have used [gosaml](https://github.com/mattbaird/gosaml) and it works pretty good but there is also [go-saml](https://github.com/RobotsAndPencils/go-saml) from robots and pencils.

I figured after a year, it would be good to answer this question because it would still be good to have some sort of answer here for people looking for SAML libraries for Go.

Comment: Thanks for the links. For my purposes the [go-saml](https://github.com/RobotsAndPencils/go-saml) project looks more useful, since in order to implement SAML SSO I'll need to generate SAML authRequests *and* validate SAML authResponses.

Comment: Sweet. I am glad that I could help in some sense. I have used both and both are pretty decent. Validation is always a fun thing to deal with.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't seen a SAML implementation for Go, but you could use a server that already implements it in front of your app.

One of the best supported SAML implementations is [Shibboleth](http://shibboleth.net). The apache module is the most mature, and is probably the easiest method to use, since you just put your app behind a reverse proxy in apache. There's also a fastcgi authenticator, which uses the same backend, but I can't speak for it's ease of implementation.

If you just need a service-provider, the simplest SAML binding is HTTP-POST-SimpleSign. I made a [proof-of-concept implementation](https://github.com/jbardin/python-saml) in python, to try and demonstrate the simplest SP I could. I make no claims to the robustness of this module, but you can see that it *could* be done with not too much code. That's assuming the Identity Providers you're working with support this binding. And as always, be wary when deploying any custom security-related code.

Comment: +1 for linking to a proof of concept implementation. It appears that your Assertion Checking Service (attached to relative URL /SSO) doesn't actually do anything except print the attributes of the "authResponse" security assertion - at the very least you *should* validate the IdP signature - but I take your point to be that it doesn't take much to generate an "authRequest" and catch the authResponse for further processing (& additional validation). True, but even if I only care about SSO login with POST bindings there are many details to get wrong when implementing from scratch.

Comment: @Peter - agree, and that's why I never took this little lib any further. I wrote this a while back, but I remember it definitely verifying the IdP signature (via M2Crypto). You need the IdP's cert in pem, and saml.py:118 throws a SAML_Error if the sig fails. I haven't checked what is entailed for basic signing/verification in Go yet though.

Comment: In fact, I want my ACS to do a good deal *more* than simply validate the IdP signature, and one of the advantages of using a finished library (like [SimpleSAMLphp](http://simplesamlphp.org/), which I have used successfully to implement SP logic before) is that somebody has already built the machinery for handling "trust relationship metadata". I also know that I could build a reverse proxy to hide the "federated identity" implementation details from the rest of my application - the point is precisely that I would like to use Go to implement the proxy.

Comment: Ah, yes - federation requires a lot more work. My example assumes that the cert is exchanged via a secure side-channel, which is still a very common use case. Though my disclaimer for anyone else reading is still, *don't use this code in production* (or at least be very careful, and vet everything).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to validate SAML replies from AWS IdP in your assertion consumer endpoint then you better go with https://github.com/crewjam/saml as it does not rely on libxmlsec1 system library.

For some reason libxmlsec1 does not validate SAML replies from some IdP (AWS) successfully (supposedly because of some undefined namespaces).