# Enable single sign on

Tags: azure, go, single-sign-on

Hi I have to develop a framework to enable single sign on for an application that my organisation develops.I want the framework to be in GOLANG.I want to authenticate the users with azure active directory details.How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD can provide auth via WS-Fed, SAML-P, OAuth2 and OpenID Connect.  As long as you develop using one of those then your application can be registered in Azure AD as an application and can leverage the standard protocols listed above.

Comment: Could you suggest me which one is the best among them to use along with golang?

Comment: It will depend on library support for the protocol (SAML, etc) and the type of application you're building (web, mobile native, etc). You'll most likely find answers to that elsewhere on SO such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310828/is-there-a-saml-library-for-the-go-language